# How to get Rich Text Box Character Color?

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application, rich-text-editor

I have one rich text box application an i have to perform two operation withing.

1) I have to highlight only some percent of character of rich text box text.

Example: Suppose I have 100 character without white space. In this i need validation that user can not be highlight only some allowed characters.

Means I have 100 character and admin allow only for 20% then user can only highlight only 20 percent. Character base color is black and means user can not change color of any 80 character. User can only change 20 characters in any color.

2) Suppose User highlighted any text. Then user user have ability to mark any text with that highlighted as comment.

I have done lot of searches for that but i didn't get any solution please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm assuming this is a WPF RichTextBox you're inquiring about, based on the 'desktop-application' tag. So in the WPF RichTextBox you have a TextRange object, which has an [ApplyPropertyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.applypropertyvalue.aspx) on it.

So you would want to get a TextRange that spans the characters that you want then apply the property TextElement.Foreground to a brush of your choice.

For example, if you wanted to hilight characters 20-40 as red you might do something like this:

```
var range = new TextRange(
  rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(20),
  rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(40));
range.ApplyProperty(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```

It's worth noting that when you apply a property like this, internally the text will be broken up into multiple runs and getting the position by offset will not work in the same way. In that case you should get a TextRange for the entire document and call ClearAllProperties or use a TextPointer and iterate over the runs.

Comment: this is simple window application.

Comment: So you're saying its windows forms instead?